# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column "bucket_id" is of type integer but expression is of type uuid

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, uuid

I am implementing a postgresql database, which consists of two tables. For this, using flask-sqlalchemy, I have implemented two models, `bucket` and `bucket_column`, where the identifier of `bucket` is a uuid (universally unique identifier) and `bucket_column` is identified by two values, the column identifier and the bucket identifier. So, both models maintain a one-to-many relationship. My problem lies in when I try to add a column to `bucket_column`, using a real bucket identifier, the code throws the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column "bucket_id" is of type integer but expression is of type uuid
LINE 1: ...umn (bucket_id, column_name, column_type) VALUES ('a2044600-...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

[SQL: INSERT INTO bucket_column (bucket_id, column_name, column_type) VALUES (%(bucket_id)s::UUID, %(column_name)s, %(column_type)s) RETURNING bucket_column.column_id]
[parameters: {'bucket_id': UUID('a2044600-3dd1-4ed3-8037-5146e3c92afd'), 'column_name': 'hola', 'column_type': 'String'}]
```

This is the code I've written:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import psycopg2
import uuid

app = app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5000/example' 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app) 

class bucket(db.Model): 
    # attributes 
    bucket_id   = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid = True), primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4)
    bucket_path = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable = False)
    bucket_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable = False)
    # relationships
    bucket_cols = db.relationship('bucket_column', backref = 'bucket')
    # constraint 
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint(bucket_name, bucket_path, name = 'idx_bucket'), )
    # initialize 
    def __init__(self, path : str, name : str) -> None :
        self.bucket_path = path
        self.bucket_name = name 
    # representation
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<The bucket ({self.bucket_id}) is in {self.bucket_path}/{self.bucket_name}>'

class eda_bucket_column(db.Model):
    # attributes
    bucket_id   = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid = True), db.ForeignKey('bucket.bucket_id'), default = uuid.uuid4)
    column_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement = True)
    column_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable = False)
    column_type = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable = True)
    # constraints 
    __table_args__ = (db.PrimaryKeyConstraint(bucket_id, column_id, name = 'bucket_column_pk'), )
    # initialize 
    def __init__(self, bucket_id : uuid, name : str, type : str) -> None:
        self.bucket_id = bucket_id 
        self.column_name = name 
        self.column_type = type
    # representation
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<The column ({self.bucket_id}, {self.column_id}) is called {self.column_name} and its type is {self.column_type}>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        
    app.run(debug=True, port = 5000, host="0.0.0.0")

@app.route('/')
def addColumn():
    idBuc = db.session.query(eda_bucket).first().bucket_id
    col = eda_bucket_column(idBuc, 'hola', 'String')
    db.session.add( col )
    db.session.commit()
```

I want to interact with both models without problems, since I can add any kind of value in `bucket` but I cannot do anything in `bucket_column`.

Comment: 1) The model is `eda_bucket_column`, the INSERT says `INSERT INTO bucket_column ...`. Are you working on correct table? 2) Use `psql` to see what the actual table definitions are in the database. Maybe a migration or change was missed?